# Basic C# Unity2D movement script not functioning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

Hi there fellow Overflowers!
I have recently dived into C# in Unity, because I believe that it has more functionality than UnityScript, and I come from a C++ background. Referencing some code from a 2D script in the Sample Assets, I have tried to create my own. The code is below:

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {
//Variables
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool facingForward = true; //for Flip() Function
    bool isGround = true; //for Grounded() Function
    public float maxSpeed = 5.0f; //Terminal sideways velocity
    public float HorizonAxis; //Checks for a/d movement 
    public float jumpFloat = 1000.0f; //Modular, use Unity Editor
    public float moveFloat = 400.0f; // "                       "

    void Start() {

        //transform.position(0,0,0);

    }

    void Flip() {
        facingForward = !facingForward; //switches boolean
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale; //assigns vector to localscale of Player
        theScale.x *= -1; //if x = 1, position becomes -1 and thus flips
        transform.localScale = theScale; //reassigns the localscale to update theScale
    }
    bool Grounded() {
        if (transform.position.y > 1) { //if position of gameObject is greater that 1, not grounded
            isGround = false;
        } else {
            isGround = true;
        }
        return isGround; //function returns true or false for isGround
    }

    void Update() {
        HorizonAxis = /*UnityEngine.*/Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"); //assigns HorizonAxis to a/d movement from UnityEngine.Input
        if (HorizonAxis * rigidbody2D.velocity.x > maxSpeed) { // if Input a/d by current x velocity of gameObject is greater than maxSpeed             
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (Mathf.Sign (rigidbody2D.velocity.x) * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y); //1 or -1 times the max speed, depending on direction
    }

    else if (HorizonAxis * rigidbody2D.velocity.x < maxSpeed) { //if Input a/d is less than terminal velocity
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right * HorizonAxis * moveFloat); //add force to the right equivilant to Input by scalar moveFloat
    }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) { //If Space
            if(isGround) { //and isGround returns true
                rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0.0f, jumpFloat)); //add upwards force to bottom of rigidbody2D
                isGround = false; //Resets isGround value
            }
        }
        if (HorizonAxis > 0 && !facingForward) {//if UnityEngine.Input is to the right and facing left
            Flip (); //execute
        }
        else if (HorizonAxis < 0 && facingForward) { //else
                    Flip (); //execute 
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the code just doesn't work. I get no compile errors, but any Input does not effect the current position of the character. Should I be using transform.Translate to change the position, or stick with AddForce to a Vector2 until the character hits a maxSpeed?

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with MonoDevelop?

Comment: Your script works for me.  Is there something else causing it to not be able to move?

Comment: I actually noticed that there was a linking error between the player and the script, which i resolved. The problem I have now is that the controls are really jerky and dont really work smoothly, any suggestions?

Comment: When you are dealing with rigid bodies and forces, you should use FixedUpdate() instead of Update().  See the Unity description here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Comment: That has helped a lot with the side to side movement. I am having issues with the fact that when the character is in mid air, i cant apply and force to him (the x axis motions does not comply with the y axis) and also that i cant get him to stay upright :(

Comment: EDIT: Actually fixed the Angle so he doesn't topple over. The Jumping is still an issue

Answer (score 0):

I (kinda) fixed the jerky jumping issue, basically you look for the input in the Update() function which switches a Bool in FixedUpdate()

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && playerGrounded) {
        playerJumped = true;
    }
}
```

Then in FixedUpdate() I looked for this Bool and did my AddForce

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    if (playerJumped) {
        playerJumped = false;
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        playerGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

Setting playerJumped to false makes sure it doesn't run several times and the player can't jump again because I also set the grounded to false. grounded gets set back to true when the player collides with things tagged "ground".

I'm still new to Unity and C# overall so I can't guarantee this is the best (or even a good) way. Hope I could help somehow though ;)